# plasma browser integration error

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am using kubuntu 18.04 LTS. How do I stop "plasma-browser-integration" error everytime I open firefox? I tried searching for that package in discover but couldn't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See edit below**

Plasma browser integration is **not** available in Kubuntu 18.04. This feature requires Plasma 5.13. Kubuntu 18.04 has Plasma 5.12 and will remain on 5.12 for the rest of its life.

If you have installed the [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/plasma-integration/) required for Plasma browser integration, remove it.

---

**Edit**: A Kubuntu developer [mentioned](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/73799-Plasma-Browser-Integration?p=426759&viewfull=1#post426759) that *plasma-browser-integration* **is** available for Kubuntu 18.04. But it requires adding the [Kubuntu Backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) and following the instructions in the link.

In addition to *plasma-browser-integration*, other selected packages will be updated to more recent versions than normally available. You can get an idea by looking at [this link](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=bionic).

Comment: I didn't install that extension, I guess firefox has it by default. Removing that extension stopped that notification from appearing again. Thanks